# What is the difference between char *str being null and str[0] == '\0'

Tags: c, string, pointers, char

I have a pointer `char *str;`

for a particular case, `if (!str)` is not NULL but `str[0] == '\0'`, how and when is this possible?

**Edit:0** 
Thanks for all the responses. Basically I need to pass this string as a source param in `strlcpy()` which is sag faulting because this is an empty string. It seems I need a check something like this: `if (!str || str[0] == '\0')` than do not pass to strlcpy(). Does that sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\0` is the null-byte or null-terminator. Therefore, it is seen as null. C-strings are null-terminated. That is, the first time a null-byte is seen, the string is considered complete. If nothing other than `\0` exists, it is `NULL`.

If you have information beyond this byte (this is bad practice for strings) you could try to check `str+1` which will advance passed the null-byte. In any event, `str+1` and so on could very well be garbage data and cause invalid memory accesses (causing your program to crash).

Comment: So, in this case, something past `\0` exists?

Comment: Look at my revised response. It could exist if you explicitly set it as such. However, if you expect this to be a string, it is best to null-terminate a single time. If it is some arbitrary array of bytes, then yes it is possible based on your defined convention.

Comment: Please don't call empty strings `NULL`. Those are different things. `str == NULL` means the pointer `str` contains a value that is guaranteed to not be a valid memory address. `str[0] == '\0'` means you have a pointer to valid memory (or just terribly bad luck) and the first (maybe only) byte of that memory contains the value 0, which means `str` points to an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

`str[0] == '\0'` is used to represent an **empty string** - a string of length 0.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible when a valid (non `NULL`) pointer within str points to a memory address that contains a single `\0` char.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *str = "";
```

Then `str` is a pointer to an empty string, it is not `NULL` but `*str ==  str[0] == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

`str` holds an address in memory - the address of a `char`.

`(!str)` will only return false when the value of str isn't `NULL`. In other words, when str doesn't reference the address `NULL`, which is an unusable memory address.

`*str` contains a `char`. When the *character that str points to* is `NULL`, then `(str[0] == '\0')` will return true: str is pointing to the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with two things:

First, char *str is a pointer. If it's NULL, it is not pointing at valid memory, and you cannot dereference it either as `str[0]` or `*char`.

Second, `str[0]` == '\0'` means you have a pointer that points to valid memory, and the first position in the string in the memory pointed to by str is '\0', a string terminator.

Comment: `str[0] == '\0'` does not necessarily mean invalid memory. This is a string of length zero (or empty string). This could very well be a valid chunk of memory, there is just nothing in it.